# Using for loop to populate array in document.getelementbyid

Tags: javascript

i now facing a problem with using looping on my project. Currently i have a multiple checkbox which have their own unique id example :myCheckbox,myCheckBox1,myCheckBox2,....

I don't wish to hardcore the number behind the myCheckBox, so i try to use a for loop to get it done. Somehow i dono why my for loop does work, if i hardcode it like document.getelementbyid('mycheckbox1').checked==true then it work.

Anything i miss out in my code? Please guide me through as i'm still new to web programming. Thanks

Here is my code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

        function checkDisabled(yourSubmitButton){

          for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
              if(document.getElementById("myCheckBox"+i).checked==true){
                  yourSubmitButton.disabled = false;
                    return; 
              }
          } 


            // If we have made it here, disable it
            yourSubmitButton.disabled = true;

          };
          </script>
```

Comment: If `getElementById` can't find a particular element, it will return `null`.  You cannot test `.checked` on a null object... so it will crash.  You need to test for whether `getElementById` returns a valid object or not

Comment: The code is okay as far as it goes, although there's the question of `myCheckbox` vs `myCheckbox0` (see my answer). We need to see your HTML. Also, you **never** need `== true` in conditions. And you will **need** to have 10 checkboxes for that code not to throw an error.

Comment: In general, your **best option** for figuring stuff like this out is to use the fully-featured debugger built into your browser. Press F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I or (on a Mac) Cmd+Shift+I or look in the menus, and you'll find a debugger with which you can step through code a statement at a time, look at the values of variables, see errors if there are errors that occur... There's no need to stumble around in the dark; your browser has one heck of a torch you can use.

Comment: Like the torch analogy @T.J - going to try and remember that one

Answer (score 2):

Stab in the dark: You've said in your question that your checkboxes are called `myCheckbox`, `myCheckbox1`, `myCheckBox2`, and such, but your loop is looking for `myCheckbox0`, not `myCheckbox`, on the first iteration, which would make it throw an exception when you try to read the `checked` property of `null`.